# why is super.__init__() called in it's own constructor here and is this recursion of some type?

Tags: python, dictionary, inheritance

I saw this code while learning how to add key:value pairs in a hashtable/Dictionaries. I couldn't understand the need and use of calling `super().__init()` in the constructor. Can someone pls help me out.

```
class MyDictionary(dict):  

# __init__ function 
def __init__(self): 
      
    super().__init__() 
    self = dict() 

    # Function to add key:value 
def add(self, key, value): 
      
    # Adding Values to dictionary 
    self[key] = value
```

Comment: Whatever `dict.__init__` does, you would not want to skip what it's doing in your child class, would you? (On another note `self = dict() ` does not make much sense, what's that line supposed to do?)

Comment: ohh. Right that makes sense. So does that means if I'm not planning to create a child class, I don't need to call 'super.__init()__' at all. Right?

Comment: How would you be able to call `super().__init__(...)` when doing something other than coding a child class?

Comment: I'm creating a hashmap to store a linked listed node as key and a clone-node as value. To build an add function, i referred to this code and got stuck. :/

Comment: @ManasTuteja sure but is that hashmap supposed to be a child class of `dict` or not?

Comment: @timgeb yes, it does. I got it now. Thanks for the A2A.

Comment: @trincot it did, thank you!